# Can't create donut chart using gwt-google-apis

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

I'm trying to create donut chart using gwt-google-apis. As I understand based on the [reference](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#Overview)  it's a ordinary pie chart with 'pieHole' option (it's value should be between 0.0 and 1.0). Also there is a restriction that donut does not support 'is3D' option.

I followed to the [gwt-google-apis reference](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted?tm=6) and wrote following code:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

    Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Panel panel = RootPanel.get();
            PieChart pie = new PieChart(createTable(), createOptions());
            panel.add(pie);

        }
    };
    VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback,
            PieChart.PACKAGE);

}

private AbstractDataTable createTable() {
    DataTable data = DataTable.create();
    data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Task");
    data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Hours per Day");
    data.addRows(2);
    data.setValue(0, 0, "Work");
    data.setValue(0, 1, 14);
    data.setValue(1, 0, "Sleep");
    data.setValue(1, 1, 10);
    return data;
}

private Options createOptions() {
    Options options = Options.create();
    options.setWidth(400);
    options.setHeight(240);
    options.setTitle("My Daily Activities");
    options.setOption("pieHole", "0.4");
    return options;
}
```

However, I've received ordinary pie chart without hole (I've run it only in dev mode). Any suggestions? Maybe I've missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the API of latest stable version gwt-visualization-1.1.2, that functionality is not present. The only options specific to a piechart you can set are:

```
 void   set3D(boolean is3D) 

 void   setPieResidueSliceLabel(java.lang.String label) 

 void   setPieSliceText(java.lang.String text) 

 void   setPieSliceTextStyle(TextStyle textStyle) 

 void   setSliceVisibilityThreshold(double angle)
```

You could add an issue or write the functionality yourself adding JSNI methods to PieChart.PieOptions . Take a look at [GWTProject](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html) if you are unfamiliar with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create donut chart using GWT-API
you have to write Wrapper for PieChartOptions like this

## PieOpt.java

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.JsArray;
import com.googlecode.gwt.charts.client.corechart.PieChartOptions;
import com.googlecode.gwt.charts.client.corechart.PieChartTooltip;
import com.googlecode.gwt.charts.client.options.BackgroundColor;
import com.googlecode.gwt.charts.client.options.ChartArea;
import com.googlecode.gwt.charts.client.options.Legend;
import com.googlecode.gwt.charts.client.options.PieSliceText;
import com.googlecode.gwt.charts.client.options.Slice;
import com.googlecode.gwt.charts.client.options.TextStyle;

public class PieOpt {
    private PieChartOptions _this;

    private PieOpt() {
        _this = PieChartOptions.create();
    }

    public static PieOpt newInstance() {
        return new PieOpt();
    }

    public PieChartOptions get() {
        return _this;
    }

    public final void setBackgroundColor(BackgroundColor backgroundColor) {
        _this.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
    }

    public final void setBackgroundColor(String color) {
        _this.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }

    public final void setChartArea(ChartArea chartArea) {
        _this.setChartArea(chartArea);
    }

    public final void setColors(String... colors) {
        _this.setColors(colors);
    }

    public final void setFontName(String name) {
        _this.setFontName(name);
    }

    public final void setFontSize(double size) {
        _this.setFontSize(size);
    }

    public final void setIs3D(boolean is3D) {
        _this.setIs3D(is3D);
    }

    public final void setLegend(Legend legend) {
        _this.setLegend(legend);
    }

    public final void setPieResidueSliceColor(String pieResidueSliceColor) {
        _this.setPieResidueSliceColor(pieResidueSliceColor);
    }

    public final void setPieResidueSliceLabel(String pieResidueSliceLabel) {
        _this.setPieResidueSliceLabel(pieResidueSliceLabel);
    }

    public final void setPieSliceBorderColor(String pieSliceBorderColor) {
        _this.setPieSliceBorderColor(pieSliceBorderColor);
    }

    public final void setPieSliceText(PieSliceText pieSliceText) {
        _this.setPieSliceText(pieSliceText);
    }

    public final void setPieSliceTextStyle(TextStyle pieSliceTextStyle) {
        _this.setPieSliceTextStyle(pieSliceTextStyle);
    }

    public final void setReverseCategories(boolean reverseCategories) {
        _this.setReverseCategories(reverseCategories);
    }

    public final void setSlices(JsArray<Slice> slices) {
        _this.setSlices(slices);
    }

    public final void setSliceVisibilityThreshold(
            double sliceVisibilityThreshold) {
        _this.setSliceVisibilityThreshold(sliceVisibilityThreshold);
    }

    public final void setTitle(String title) {
        _this.setTitle(title);
    }

    public final void setTitleTextStyle(TextStyle textStyle) {
        _this.setTitleTextStyle(textStyle);
    }

    public final void setTooltip(PieChartTooltip tooltip) {
        _this.setTooltip(tooltip);
    }

    public void setHole(double d) {
        setHole(get(), d);
    }

    private final native void setHole(PieChartOptions chartOptions, double d) /*-{
        chartOptions.pieHole = d;
    }-*/;
}
```

And use it like this

```
ChartLoader chartLoader = new ChartLoader(ChartPackage.CORECHART);
        chartLoader.loadApi(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pieChart = new PieChart();

                   DataTable dataTable = DataTable.create();
                                    dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Name");
                                    dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Donuts eaten");
                                    dataTable.addRows(4);
                                    dataTable.setValue(0, 0, "Michael");
                                    dataTable.setValue(1, 0, "Elisa");
                                    dataTable.setValue(2, 0, "Robert");
                                    dataTable.setValue(3, 0, "John");
                                    dataTable.setValue(0, 1, 5);
                                    dataTable.setValue(1, 1, 7);
                                    dataTable.setValue(2, 1, 3);
                                    dataTable.setValue(3, 1, 2);



               PieOpt opt = PieOpt.newInstance();
        opt.setHole(0.4);
        pieChart.draw(dataTable, opt.get());

            }
        });
```

And you are Done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FacetChart chart=new FacetChart();
chart.setData(ChartData.getData());  
chart.setFacets(new Facet("region", "Region"),new Facet("time", "Period"));  
chart.setValueProperty("value");  

chart.setTitle("Revenue");

chart.setChartType(ChartType.DOUGHNUT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a working example:

```
private PieChart.PieOptions createPieOptions() {
    PieChart.PieOptions options = PieChart.createPieOptions();
    options.set("pieHole", "0.4");

    return options;
}

private AbstractDataTable createPieTable() {
    DataTable data = DataTable.create();
    data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, LABEL);
    data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, VALUE);

    data.addRows(2);
    data.setValue(0, 0, "example");
    data.setValue(0, 1, "12");
    data.setValue(1, 0, "example number two");
    data.setValue(1, 1, "88");
    }

    return data;
}

PieChart tagsPie = new PieChart(createPieTable(), createPieOptions());
```